Error message in flask app cannot retrieve from trefle API
I am making a gardening site using trefle API using Flask. The goal is to allow the user to query for plants and find information about ideal growing conditions etc. My API key has been set up correctly, but not only can I not search plants on Trefle's wesbite:https://trefle.io/explore?search=coconut, but I cannot use requests to get data either. My code:
BASE_URL = 'https://trefle.io/api/v1/plants/search'

@app.route('/plant', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def plant():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        plant_name = request.form.get('name') 

        if not plant_name:
            return jsonify({'error': 'Plant name is required'}), 400

        try:
            # Construct the Trefle API query
            response = requests.get(
                BASE_URL,
                params={'token': TREFLE_API_KEY,'q': plant_name} 
            )
            response.raise_for_status() 

            plant_data = response.json()

            if plant_data.get('data'):
                # Extract growing information
                plant_info = [
                    {
                        "Name": plant.get('common_name', "N/A"),
                        "Scientific Name": plant.get('scientific_name', "N/A"),
                        "Light": plant.get('main_species', {}).get('growth', {}).get('light', "unknown"),
                        "Atmospheric Humidity": plant.get('main_species', {}).get('growth', {}).get('atmospheric_humidity', "unknown"),
                        "pH": f"Best between {plant.get('main_species', {}).get('growth', {}).get('ph_min', 'unknown')} and {plant.get('main_species', {}).get('growth', {}).get('ph_max', 'unknown')}",
                        "Precipitations": f"Best between {plant.get('main_species', {}).get('growth', {}).get('precipitation_min', 'unknown')} and {plant.get('main_species', {}).get('growth', {}).get('precipitation_max', 'unknown')}",
                        "Temperature": f"Best between {plant.get('main_species', {}).get('growth', {}).get('temperature_min', 'unknown')}°C and {plant.get('main_species', {}).get('growth', {}).get('temperature_max', 'unknown')}°C",
                    }
                    for plant in plant_data['data']
                ]

                return render_template('plant.html', layout=layout_template, user_name=check_name(), plants=plant_info)

            return jsonify({'message': 'No plants found for your query.'}), 404

        except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
            return jsonify({'error': 'Failed to fetch data from the Trefle API', 'details': str(e)}), 500

    return render_template('plant.html', layout=layout_template, user_name=check_name(), plants=None)


I tried quering with the plant "coconut" but I get:
    "details": "500 Server Error: Internal Server Error for url: https://trefle.io/api/v1/plants/search?q=coconut&token=MY_TOKEN(the token is correct)",
    "error": "Failed to fetch data from the Trefle API"
}

Even by using my browser I can not retrieve it and get:

We're sorry, but something went wrong.
If you are the application owner check the logs for more information.


It seems that they closed the project 3 years ago:   https://x.com/trefle_api/status/1389232291302490117

searching in their github it seen that this issue comes from july.
here is the link to the github issue tracker Search error #122

Thanks for the help! Do you know any alternatives to trefle or other ways to access the data?
